# How to add / remove rows in array in hybrid Vue project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So, I built this little webapp to help me prioritize the ideas I want to build. https://codepen.io/aibrindley/pen/ELXajM

I am now trying to make it possible to add items to the array from the interface.  It would also be nice to be able to remove items.

The code is a bit of a hybrid approach to using Vue.

Just looking at the way names are set and shown

```
<td>{{ product.name }}</td>
<td><input id="iname"/></td>
```

and the item is added to the list on a button click

```
function addItem() {
  var iname = document.getElementById("iname").value
  products[products.length + 1].name = iname
```

I know that I should be setting the array inside of

```
new Vue({})
```

but doing so made adding up the total column fail...

Could someone please help! I'm sure there is something simple I am missing.

edit: codepen updated and working thanks to @Sphinx
see `@click="addItemByVue();"` in the HTML and `addItemByVue` in the JS

Comment: I don't suggest a hybrid approach, what was the failure when setting within Vue?

Comment: As @phix said, it is not a good idea for hybrid. for your use case, JQuery will be better than Vue. Anyway, you can bind click event for 'Add' button, then add new object to this.sort. like [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OZgNmB)

Comment: @Phix - I kind of knew that, but figured with such a simple project it would be easier...

Comment: @Sphinx - thank you! my codepen is updated and working per your addition.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
created: {
  window.addItem = this.addItemByVue.bind(this)
}
```